# block the dates in the calendar in sharepoint, once the leave is approved

Tags: sharepoint, calendar

I have created a leave planner in Sharepoint and have automated the leave approval and balance update using SharePoint designer.

Now there is a requirement to built a calendar in sharepoint that gets updated automatically for every employee, when their leave is approved or cancelled after the approval. Basically, I need to set up something like calendar overlay, but with a feature that the calendar automatically blocks the dates for which the employee has applied leave and can be seen to the manager in the single calendar.

Is there a way we can do this, because I am unable to figure out any flow to automate this using Sharepoint designer?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have created leave approval system on a SP list. You can create a workflow on that list with SP Designer which will work when the list is updated. It will block the dates with employee details on a calendar you have created and give permissions to specific users. Or you can change the permissions on item level in workflow.

Comment: Yes, I have created it on SharePoint. I am unclear on what you have suggested but I believe I have done something similar to that.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to "Add an app Calendar" and set an action to create an event in the calendar, once the leave is approved.
1. Add this action to the flow where you have mentioned other actions to happen once the leave is approved:

- Create item in "Calendar", Output to variable "create"
- Set "Start Time" to "From Date" from your current item
  -Set "End Time" to "To Date" from your current item

  2. This will block your calendar dates and will show up in share point calendar
  3. You can also set display message based on your choice, such as, "XYZ is on leave"